# Firebase Fcm create a token based on when a user log in?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have to update token whenever a user signs in in cloud Firestore database.I have a code below
in which it updates based on user logged in but i have to like First login the app then close it and  again open it to the token to save in the database.On first time while login it doesn't
Save the token.please help me

```
Future<void> setupToken() async {
    // Get the token each time the application loads

    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    String? token1 = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    print('Token: $token1');

     FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((firebaseUser) {
       if(firebaseUser != null){
       createtoken(token1!);
      // print(firebaseUser);
       }else{
       print("Please Login");
       print(firebaseUser);
       }
    });

  }
  //
  Future<void> createtoken(String token2) async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .update({'token': token2});
    print("created token");
  }
```

I tried  using

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((firebaseUser) {
       if(firebaseUser != null){
       createtoken(token1!);
      // print(firebaseUser);
       }else{
       print("Please Login");
       print(firebaseUser);
       }
    }); 
t
```

o work the code but first time login doesn't actually create the toke for device.Only second time it does.
I want to listen to the changes of firebase user and the createtoken function should automatically work based on whether the user logs in and not create when logged out